# Gradle plugin for XML Beans

Tags: gradle, xmlbeans, gradle-plugin

I am trying to write a Gradle plugin for XML Beans.  I have started with one of the 'Hello from Gradle' plugin examples, and also a plugin published by R. Artavia [here](http://radicalcoder.com/2012/04/compiling-xml-schemas-using-gradle-and-xmlbeans/).  That plugin went straight to jar - I am trying to only generate source.  The generated source must then be compiled with other project source and included in a single jar.  Other goals include
- full plugin - all I should need is "apply plugin: 'xmlbean'"
- I can configure source/code gen location and some features if I want to
- It detects whether it needs to be rebuilt. (well, eventually!!!)

I am off to a pretty good start, but am blocked defining a new sourceSet.  I am getting an error "No such property 'srcDirs'" (or 'srcDir').  It seems there is something I have to define someplace to make a new sourceSet work but I cannot find it.  I have tried several different syntaxes (with/without equal sign, brackets, srcDir/srcDirs, etc. - nothing is working...

What do I need to do inside a plugin to make a new sourceSet entry be properly recognized?

Thank you!
JKE

File: xmlbean.gradle (includes greeting plugin for the moment for debugging)

```
apply plugin: xmlbean
apply plugin: 'java'

xmlbean {
  message = 'Hi'
  greeter = 'Gradle'
}

class xmlbean implements Plugin<Project> {

  void apply(Project project) {

    project.extensions.create("xmlbean", xmlbeanExtension)
    Task xmlbeanTask = project.task('xmlbean')
    xmlbeanTask << {

      project.configurations {
        xmlbeans
      }

      project.dependencies {
        xmlbeans 'org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.5.0'
      }

      project.sourceSets {
        main {
          java {
            srcDirs += '$project.buildDir/generated-source/xmlbeans'
          }
        }
        xmlbeans {
          srcDirs = ['src/main/xsd']
        }
      }

      ant.taskdef(name: 'xmlbean',
                  classname: 'org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.XMLBean',
                  classpath: project.configurations.xmlbeans.asPath)
      ant.xmlbean(schema: project.sourceSets.xmlbean.srcDir,
                  srconly: true,
                  srcgendir: "$project.buildDir/generated-sources/xmlbeans",
                  classpath: project.configurations.xmlbeans.asPath)

      println "${project.xmlbean.message} from ${project.xmlbean.greeter}"
    }
    project.compileJava.dependsOn(xmlbeanTask)
  }
}

class xmlbeanExtension {
  String message
  String greeter
}
```

File: build.gradle

```
apply from: '../gradle/xmlbeans.gradle'

dependencies {
  compile "xalan:xalan:$ver_xalan",
          ":viz-common:0.0.1",
          ":uform-repository:0.1.0"
}
```

Console: Error message:

```
:idk:xmlbean FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\jdev\cpc-maven\try.g2\comotion\gradle\xmlbeans.gradle' line: 32

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':idk:xmlbean'.
> No such property: srcDirs for class: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSet_Decorated
...
BUILD FAILED
```

Gradle info: version 2.5 / groovy 2.3.10 / JVM 7u55 on Windows 7 AMD64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to become familiar with the Gradle DSL reference guide, because it's a huge help in situations like this. For example, if you click on the `sourceSets { }` link in the left navigation bar, you're taken to [this section](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:sourceSets(groovy.lang.Closure)) on source sets.

From there, you'll discover that the `sourceSets {}` block is backed by a class, `SourceSetContainer`. The next level of configuration nested inside is backed by a `SourceSet` object, and then within that you have one or more `SourceDirectorySet` configurations. When you follow the link to [`SourceDirectorySet`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/SourceDirectorySet.html), you'll see that there are `getSrcDirs()` and `setSrcDirs()` methods.

So how does this help? If you look closely at the exception, you'll see that Gradle is saying it can't find a `srcDirs` property on `DefaultSourceSet_Decorated`, which you can hopefully infer is an instance of `SourceSet`. That interface does *not* have an `srcDirs` property. That's because your `xmlbeans {}` block is configuring a `SourceSet`, not a `SourceDirectorySet`. You need to add another nested configuration to gain access to `srcDirs`.

At this point, I'm wondering whether a new source set is the appropriate solution. Unfortunately it's not clear to me exactly what the plugin should be doing, so I can't offer any alternatives at this point.

Comment: Thank you @peter-ledbrook - somehow I didn't see it the next day.
  The manual is decent but groovy is new to me and there are things I don't see yet; so as a temporary workaround  I just coded a string into the configuration block and passed that to the XMLBean tool.

I think what you're telling me - in "newbie" terms, is that I need to move the "xmlbeans { }" block from being a sibling of 'main' to either a sibling of 'java' inside main, or at least somewhere 'that deep'.  I had tried both, but got errors both ways.

Comment: It looks like sometimes the notation is defining something with new fields or local variables/properties, and sometimes the fields have to already exist, and I haven't figured out when each of these situations applies.

Comment: The `main` is the part you can replace. So you would go for `sourceSets { xmlbeans { java { srcDirs = "..." } } }`. However, if it doesn't contain Java source, then I don't think you should create a source set at all.

Comment: In fact, perhaps you should be adding "src/main/xsd" as a resource directory: `sourceSets { main { resources { srcDir "src/main/xsd" } } }`. It depends what should be happening to the XSD files.